How do I shuffle sentences within a string using Python?
I have a string with sentences that look like this:
Tekken 3 is best game. I had played many games. But tekken 5 is love
I want to rearrange sentences to look something like:
But tekken 5 is love. Tekken 3 is best game. I had played many games.
I don't know how to specifically select random sentences. Each of my examples are about 500 to 600 words. Thanks.

You can use the split method : my_list = my_string.split(".")
Use your point as separator : it will generate a list with the different elements separated. Then you can use for example random.randint(1, len(my_list)) to select a random element from the list. Then you can concatenate them.

@AntonB be careful about this. random.randint(1, len(my_list)) may return the same index multiple times.

True. I guess you can just iterate,, choose an element from the list, remove it from said list, and then select an other random number on the remaining list.

random.shuffle

You could split your text into sentences, using "." plus whitespace(s) as a separator. But first import re and random
text = "Tekken 3 is best game. I had played many games. But tekken 5 is love."

sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[.])\s+', text)

If you want you may add other possible separators like ? and !.
Then you rearrange the sentences.
random.shuffle(sentences)

Then you make a new text from them.
new_text = ' '.join(sentences)
    
print(new_text)


Always choose random one can you edit code thanks

Your regular expression is not splitting on dot. Remove the space preceding I in the string to see what happens. Perhaps you could explain why you think it should work

der_weisse_Rabe tha nks you so much sir

@ SIGHUP, well yes it is splitted on dot plus whitespace. Sentences in a text are splited like that, why would you delete the space?
Regarding shuffle, yeah, at first I thoght the OP wanted to rearrange the text from the last sentence to the first one.

@der_weisse_Rabe You miss my point. Your explanation is that you're splitting on dot when in fact, as you now say in your comment, you're actually splitting on a dot and 1 or more spaces. Maybe I'm just being pedantic

@SIGHUP I see. OK, maybe it is really not obvious enough, I corrected the explanation

You can use shuffle():
import re, random


def _rearrange(text):
    ss = re.split(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])\.\s+(?=[A-Z0-9])', text)
    random.shuffle(ss)
    res = '. '.join(ss)

    if not res.endswith('.'):
        res += '.'

    return res


text = "Tekken 3 is the best game. I have played many games. But Tekken 5 is love....but Tekken 5 is love.   1 of the words .... would be to .... end.   I guess"
print(_rearrange(text))


Prints
But Tekken 5 is love....but Tekken 5 is love. I have played many games. 1 of the words .... would be to .... end. I guess. Tekken 3 is the best game.
(?<=[a-z0-9])\.\s+(?=[A-Z0-9])

You can add additional limits in this pattern, depending on how your sentences may look like.


If your strings are as simple as your provided example, you could just split by periods, shuffle, and recombine.
Split by ". "
text = "Tekken 3 is best game. I had played many games. But tekken 5 is love."
sentences = text.split(". ")
Shuffle
shuffled_sentences = random.shuffle(sentences)
You will need to import random
Recombine
shuffled_text = ". ".join(shuffled_sentences)
Notice that I separated and combined the sentences with ". ", including the whitespace after the period.
This is a simple example, but your input may be more complex.
You said you had long articles, so they may break this if:

They use alternate punctuation (!?)
They have instances of ". " that aren't the end of a sentence, like The best parts are 1. the game, 2. the visuals...

In that case you could use regex like the other answers suggest.
